# How do I pair a type to a factory routine in another assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm attempting to make a generic routine within my program that will instantiate objects for me. The routines actually responsible for calling new Object() are located within a different assembly in a factory that must be instantiated.

```
namespace ExternalLib
{
    class Object1Factory
    {
        public Object1 getObject1()
            //...
    }
    class Object2Factory
        // Same implementation as Object1Factory
}
```

I am attempting to provide a routine with my application that will allow me to call the appropriate routine to "new up" the object for me.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
            //...
        static Object getNewObject(string typeName)
        {
            //This is where I have problems
        }
    }
}
```

I have access to the source code of both the external library as well as my program, although an entire re-write of the architecture is too costly.

**What I've tried**:
My initial idea was to use custom attributes on the factory and/or factory routine and use reflection to grab the method, then call the method. I was originally using the signature `private static T getNew<T>()` and attempting to use a switch statement on the type parameter, but realised `getNewObject(string typeName)` would be easier. Factories have the same constructor signatures, but have no inheritance link.

**In summation**: Routine to create objects is in factory in another assembly, how do I automatically call those routines to get objects based on type?

Comment: Is the assembly linked to your program? Or is it a completely external assembly that needs to be loaded first?

Comment: Perhaps some sort of an abstract factory pattern is what you're looking for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this as opposed to simply doing `new MyClass()` in code?  As in, what scenario is dictating the need for this reflection based instantiation.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I'm attempting to implement a LINQ provider, but there is already a current way to grab data via factories (Data Objects are created manually). These factories already have all the SQL logic baked into them, so I'm attempting to abstract that layer, as opposed to scraping it and having LINQ formulate all the SQL

Comment: Why do the types all require separate factories? Can you not just have a single factory class?

Comment: @Richard All the data classes are manually created, and have the SQL logic and DB => object binding baked into the factories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to continue down this path - can you put all of the factory methods in a single factory class called something like 'ObjectFactory'?

```
Type t = typeof(OtherAssembly.ObjectFactory);

MethodInfo m = t.GetMethods().Where(a => a.ReturnType.Name == typeName).FirstOrDefault();

return m.Invoke(null, new object[] { /* PARAMETERS */ });
```

**EDIT** - response to James's comment on question stating he'd prefer to keep factory classes separate:

(Using Martin's idea below and relies on all Factory classes being names "[Type]Factory")

(Also has non-static methods on factory class)

```
Type t = Type.GetType(String.Format("OtherAssembly.{0}Factory", typeName));

var myFactory = Activator.CreateInstance( t );

MethodInfo m = t.GetMethods().Where(a => a.ReturnType.Name == typeName).FirstOrDefault();

return m.Invoke(myFactory, new object[] { /* PARAMETERS */ });
```

Comment: Just to note, if the factories have to be instantiated you can do `var myFactory = Activator.CreateInstance( t );` and then pass t as the object parameter (where you use null above)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something in the question, but what's wrong with just using this:

```
static Object getNewObject(string typeName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);      
}
```

Maybe with a bit of string manipulation and reflection if typeName is say Object1 and you want to get hold of Object1Factory, and then using reflection to invoke the getObject1() method on the factory

If you can pass in typeName as say "MyNameSpace.Object1, Object1Assembly" then it will load it from the relevant assembly.

Comment: I think the missing piece is the disconnect of the factory assembly not referencing the type's assembly - however, that can be specified in the type name I think.

Answer (score 0):

Purely in response to what you tried, if you alter the signature to:

```
static T GetNew<T>() where T : new()
{
    // Then you can do this:
    return new T();
}
```

It places a generic constraint for a public parameterless constructor on the type `T`. However, this is pointless as calling code would look like this:

```
var obj = GetNew<MyClass>();
```

Whereas it would normally just look like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
```

So I wouldn't go for it as a solution, but it would have worked and would have negated the need for the switch statement.